# Android studio project was deleted. Have apk on phone

Tags: android, apk

So I deleted my Android Studio Project by accident but I have the updated .apk from the last time I ran the project on my phone.  I got the apk using MyAppSharer and tried to decompile it using dex2jar and jd-gui but the class files I got back were not the actual classes that I wrote.  The packages were com.android.tools.fd.runtime and com.android.tools.

Is there any other way to get the actual apps class files?

I'm using Ubuntu and my phone has root.

Edit: I said I had already successfully decompiled the .apk.  The classes.dex files did not have the class files I wrote.

Comment: Nothing to do. You can't get the excat sources of the apk.

Answer (score 1):

In my apk.zip file there was another zip file named instant-run.zip.  Inside there were about 15 .dex files.  Some of the .dex files that were named slice_0-9-classes.dex contained the java files I was looking for.